# How to restore ctrl and capslock in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I modified `/etc/default/keyboard`, changing

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to:

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"
```

and used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to swap ctrl and capslock. Now I want restore it. But I just can use the same way to restore once only, it will not remain when I reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gnome-tweak-tools`. Run `gnome-tweaks` and in keyboard section you`ll find a button to edit advanced keyboard settings. You'll find what you want there.